# Update database when user click at a checkbox

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I made a model to control the existence of a specific list of customer documents.

**models.py**

```
class PersonalDocumentation(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Project')   
    cnd = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='CND proponente')
    producer_registration = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Inscrição de produtor rural')
    sales_invoices_agriculture = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Notas de comercialização agrícolas (3 anos)')
    sales_invoices_livestock = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Notas de comercialização pecuária (5 anos)')
    rg = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name="RG")
    cpf = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='CPF')
    wedding_certificate = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Certidão de casamento')
    rg_spouse = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='RG conjuge')
    cpf_spouse = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='CPF conjuge')
```

I would like to show this data in checkbox format and for the database to be updated when user check/uncheck some item.
The only way I encontered to do this is making one url for each document

I started to think that maybe the model I created is not the best option. And maybe making just one field with a list of documents owned by the client is better.

Comment: Another option is to add another event handler when the checkbox is clicked. This event handler would trigger DB updating.

Answer (score 0):

You want to work with a pattern like this:

**views.py**

```py
def update_personal_documentation(request):
    
    ''' this method unpacks a post request and does something with it '''

    # unpack request:
    date = request.POST.get('date')

    # do something with date
    ...

    # create the response:
    response = {'message':'OK'}

    return JsonResponse(response)
```

**index.html**

```html
<button id='btn'>Click Me!</button>
<script src="{% static 'scripts.js' %}"></script>
```

**scripts.js**

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {

  /* this method sends a post request to the backend */

  $.ajax({
    url : 'submit_form',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
      date : new Date(),
      ...
    },
    success : function(response) {

      /* this method executes on a successful response from the backend */
     
      var message = response.message
     
      // do something with the message, route user to new page, close form
      ...

    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without javascript?

Comment: I would think unlikely - you need javascript to control the behavior of events / actions in the browser.